# subclassing Resource but uses 1 url for the resources in tastypie

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

Suppose I have MediaResource and two related(subclassed) resource as below.

```
class PopularMediaResource(MediaResource):
 def get_object_list(self, request):
  return self.Meta.queryset.order_by('-num_hits')


class UserMediaResource(MediaResource):
 def get_object_list(self,request):
  return self.Meta.queryset.filter(mediahit__user__id=request.user.id)
```

(example borrowed from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-tastypie/JGmY8tUzlX0)
This works fine, but I'll have to use different URL for each of these resources

```
eg, /api/v1/MediaResource/
/api/v1/PopularMediaResource/
/api/v1/UserMediaResource/
```

and so on..

So `having multiple resource classes` is the typical way of using tastypie when you want to return `different set` of the resource?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use filtering and ordering mechanism.

Here is the documentation:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#basic-filtering

Comment: can you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645058/django-tastypie-multiple-urls-for-a-single-resources-list? it boils down to the problem of serving different set(filtered) resource.  `/api/v1/image/ /api/v1/image/user/{user_id} /api/v1/image/like/user/{user_id}` I don't think there's a way of supplying filtering option via URL param for the `/api/v1/image/like/user/{user_id}` because of the complexity of the query.